# convert video/webm;codecs=vp9 to .flac

Tags: audio, webm, flac, vp9

I have a file in the video/webm;codecs=vp9 format and would like to convert it to .flac audio format?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

yes it is possible through ffmpeg .You need to install it then  in your terminal
do   **ffmpeg -i audio.webm -c:a flac audio.flac**